# MySQLでcase文のカラムにwhereで条件指定できない

Tags: sql

MySQLでのcaseとwhereについて質問です。
以下のようなテーブルがあります。

```
project_id|item_id|value
----------+-------+-----
1         |67     |5
1         |68     |5
2         |67     |6
2         |68     |6
```

item_idが67が5以上かつitem_id68が５以上のproject_idを求める SQLで困ってます。

以下のようにcase文で縦持ちを横にします。

```
SELECT 
    project_id,
        MIN(CASE item_id
            WHEN 67 THEN value
        END) AS 'c67',
        MIN(CASE item_id
            WHEN 68 THEN value
        END) AS 'c68'
FROM
    results
```

上記で以下が取れます。

```
project_id|c67|c68
----------+---+-----
1         |5  |5
```

**編集者註記：project_idが2のものは取得できないので除外**

上記のSQLをサブクエリにすれば取れると思い以下のSQLを書きました。

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        project_id,
            MIN(CASE item_id
                WHEN 67 THEN value
            END) AS 'c67',
            MIN(CASE item_id
                WHEN 68 THEN value
            END) AS 'c68'
    FROM
        results
    GROUP BY project_id) AS temp
WHERE
    'c67' >= 5 AND 'c68' >= 5
```

しかし、０件になってしまいます。

case文を使ったカラムには条件を指定できないのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

最終行にてシングルクォートでカラム名を指定されている箇所に問題がありました。

MySQLではカラム名をくくる記号は `(@+SHIFT) です。

ですので、WHERE句は、次のようにすると期待される動作になると思います。

```
WHERE `c67` >= 5 and `c68` >=5
```

以下、余談です。

2つのSQLを比較してみましたが、下のSQLにはGROUP BYにてproject_idで絞り込んでいますが、上のSQLでは特に絞り込んでいませんでした。  
そのためSQLの実行結果については、 **編集者註記** の行にて訂正しました。

Answer (score 0):

サブクエリではなく、`HAVING` を使ってみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
SELECT * FROM results;
=>
+------------+---------+-------+
| project_id | item_id | value |
+------------+---------+-------+
|          1 |      67 |     5 |
|          1 |      68 |     5 |
|          2 |      67 |     6 |
|          2 |      68 |     6 |
|          3 |      67 |     4 |
|          3 |      68 |     8 |
+------------+---------+-------+

SELECT 
    project_id,
        MIN(CASE item_id
            WHEN 67 THEN value
        END) AS 'c67',
        MIN(CASE item_id
            WHEN 68 THEN value
        END) AS 'c68'
FROM
    results
GROUP BY project_id
HAVING c67 >= 5 AND c68 >= 5
=>
+------------+------+------+
| project_id | c67  | c68  |
+------------+------+------+
|          1 |    5 |    5 |
|          2 |    6 |    6 |
+------------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

別解

```
SELECT a.project_id, a.value c67, b.value c68 
FROM (
    SELECT project_id, value FROM results WHERE item_id = 67 AND value >= 5
) AS a INNER JOIN (
    SELECT project_id, value FROM results WHERE item_id = 68 AND value >= 5
) AS b ON a.project_id = b.project_id;
```

project_id と item_id が複合ユニークであれば、上記SQL文でも期待する結果を取得できます。
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ca66/1